# JavaScript/Coffeescript sum objects

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js

I would love to "add/merge" (not sure how to call that) some objects in this manner:

```
obj1 = { 
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 1
}

obj2 = { 
  a: 1,
  b: 1
}

obj1 + obj2 => { a: 2, b: 2, c: 1 }
```

Is there any way of achieving this? Tried, `Object.assign(obj1, obj2`) but It will not add   properties like I need it to be done (it returns in `{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1`})

Comment: Nothing built-in like `Object.assign`, but it's trivial to implement. What *else* have you tried since you know `Object.assign` doesn't do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to do it but you can enumerate the properties of one object and add their values to another.

```js
const a = { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 };
const b = { a: 1, b: 1 };
for(const prop in b) {
  a[prop] = (prop in a ? a[prop] : 0) + b[prop];
}
console.log(a);
```

The `prop in a` check is so that we don't end up with `NaN` by adding `undefined` to the value in `b`.

You could use `reduce` to combine `n` number of objects like so:

```js
const a = { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 };
const b = { a: 1, b: 1 };
const c = { a: 1, c: 1 };
const result = [a, b, c].reduce((p, c) => {
  for(const prop in c) {
    p[prop] = (prop in p ? p[prop] : 0) + c[prop];
  }
  return p;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

You didn't mention how you wanted to deal with properties in the prototype chain. You should know that `for...in` will enumerate properties in the prototype chain and `prop in x` will also examine the prototype chain. If your only want to enumerate the objects own properties then you could use `Object.entries()` to get its own properties or do a `hasOwnProperty(...)` check within the `for...in` and in place of the `prop in x` check. If you don't do any prototypal inheritance with your models then you may not care.

Answer (score 1):

A quick answer:

```js
let sum = {};
let keys = new Set(Object.keys(obj1))
Object.keys(obj2).map(x => keys = keys.add(x))

keys.forEach(x => {
 let op1 = obj1[x] || 0;
 let op2 = obj2[x] || 0;
 sum[x] = op1 + op2;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty object:

```
var obj3 = {};
```

Use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to grab all the keys from both objects, then add them to the new object like so:

```
for(var i in {...obj1, ...obj2}) {
  obj3[i] = (obj1[i] || 0) + (obj2[i] || 0);
}
```

```js
var obj1 = { 
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 1
}

var obj2 = { 
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  d: 3
}

var obj3 = {};

for(var i in {...obj1, ...obj2}) {
  obj3[i] = (obj1[i] || 0) + (obj2[i] || 0);
}

console.log(obj3);
```